# Children need (advice / guidance)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

**Editted:**

I wonder which choice does **not** work in the following scenario:

> Children can also be made more vulnerable than other people because of their young age and dependence on adults, so they have specific rights to protect them. This is one of the major reasons why.................... 
>   1) children need [**advice.**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/advice) 
>   2) children need [**to be advised.**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/advise) 
>   3) children need [**guidance.**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/guidance) 
>   4) children need [**to be guided.**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/guide)

To me #2 and #4 mean the same thing. Also, #1 and #3 mean the same. Meanwhile, they all work perfectly based on dictionaries, but I don't know how a native speaker thinks about them. Are these four sentences identical in meaning? Are they interchangeable or rather when they are not intechangeable?

**Note:** I never know two synonymous concepts can be considered as interchangeable! Here, by the word "interchangeable, I am more about the impact on the audience after hearing each sentence comparing the other one.

**Note:** To me always the words "guidance" and "guide" have had a stronger demand for help, and I have my doubts if choices #3/4 mean the same as #1/3, or they are some inappropriate words in this specific example of "children". Meanwhile, I don't have any idea if a specific pair of these four are more suitable when it comes to childcare.

Also, I rarely see natives use the words "guidance" and "guide" in such situations, and it strikes me that "advice/advise are far better than guidance / guide in such a practical situation. Perhaps guidance / guide are not the words you natives ever choose in similar cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Children are 'guided' by their parents as they grow up (English speakers talk about "parental guidance".
(Source: psychcentral.com ).
"Advice" is certainly a part of this "guidance" but isn't necessarily advice about a problem.
It could be advice about anything, really.
However, the best chices either in active or passive forms are the choices with "guide/guidance".